# Adding a node to the end of a linked list

Tags: c++, insert, linked-list, traversal

I've been trying to add an item to the end of a linked list.  I think I have a handle on the concept but i'm having difficulty implementing the code.  In particular, being able to traverse a linked list and find the tail.  Here is what i have so far.  I've been at this for a while trying different things.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
##include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node *next;
};


class linkedList
{
private:
    node* ptrHead;
    node* ptrTail;

    int size;

public:
    linkedList();  //default constructor
    void display();
    void addFront(int);
    void removeFront();
    void addBack(int);
    void removeBack();
};

//default constructor
linkedList::linkedList(){
    size = 0;
    ptrHead = ptrTail = NULL;
}
//display linked list
void linkedList::display(){
    node* current = ptrHead;

    while (current != NULL) {
        cout << current->data << " "; //display current item
        current = current->next; //move to next item
    }
    cout << size;
}
//add item to front of linked list
void linkedList::addFront(int addData){

    node* n = new node;
    n->next = ptrHead;
    n->data = addData;
    ptrHead = n;

    size++;
}
//remove item from front of linked list
void linkedList::removeFront(){

    node* n = ptrHead;
    ptrHead = ptrHead->next;
    delete n;

    size--;
}

       void linkedList::addBack(int addData){   ////work in progress


        node* n = new node; //create new node
        n->data = addData;  //input data
        n->next = NULL;     //set node to point to NULL

        if ( ptrTail == NULL )  // or if ( ptrTail == nullptr )
        {
            ptrHead = n;
            ptrTail = n;
        }
        else
        {
            ptrTail->next = n;
            ptrTail = n;
        }

        size++;
    }



    //this is the test code from my main function
              int main()
        {
            //test code
            linkedList list;

            list.addFront(40);
            list.addFront(30);
            list.addFront(20);
            list.addFront(10);
            list.addFront(0);
            list.addBack(50);
            list.addBack(60);

            list.display(); //50 60 7  (the 7 is the count/size of the linked list)
            cout << endl;
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but have you considered creating a doubly-linked list? If you add a 'n->prev' pointer to 'node' you'll save from having to traverse the whole list every time you add an item to the end of the list.

Comment: I'm haven't learned doubly-linked lists yet.  I'm working my way up.  Thanks for the tip though.  : )

Comment: You've identified the primary weakness of singly-linked lists. There are some very specific scenarios where traversing from beginning to end in a linear fashion perfectly models the desired function. Like, how a foreach block will process each statement from start to end unless you add an exit condition to break the loop. A doubly-linked list works the same but contains references and pointers going in both directions. It adds more overhead but is useful in some specific cases the same way a singly-linked list can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show the definition of your linkedList.

So I can only suppose that it has data members ptrTail and ptrHead. In this case the function will look the following way

```
void linkedList::addBack(int addData)
{
   node* n = new node; //create new node
   n->data = addData;  //input data
   n->next = NULL;     //set node to point to NULL

   if ( ptrTail == NULL )  // or if ( ptrTail == nullptr )
   {
      ptrHead = n;
   }
   else
   {
      ptrTail->next = n;
   }
   ptrTail = n;

   size++;
}
```

Function `addFront` can be defined the similar way

```
void linkedList::addFront(int addData)
{
   node* n = new node; //create new node
   n->data = addData;  //input data

   if ( ptrHead == NULL )  // or if ( ptrHead == nullptr )
   {
      ptrTail = n;
   }

   n->next = ptrHead;
   ptrHead = n;

   size++;
}
```

One more function

```
void linkedList::removeFront()
{
    if ( ptrHead != NULL )
    {
        if ( ptrTail == ptrHead ) ptrTail = NULL;
        node* n = ptrHead;
        ptrHead = ptrHead->next;
        delete n;
        size--;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll gladly toss my answer out and uptick this if you consolidate the `ptrTail = n;` (I know, its fickle, but its so close and you posted first..)

Comment: I tried implementing it this way but I'm getting an odd result.  My output is 0 10 20 30 40 and after i add 50 and 60 to the back, my output is just 50 60.

Comment: @JosephK As I said you did not show your class definition. This error can be result of other wrong member function definitions. For example whether you initialize ptrHead and ptrTail by zero in the constructor.

Comment: @JosephK With this class definition the function has to work fine.

Comment: @JosephK If there is an error then it is in function addFront.

Comment: I edited my original post with your addBack function.

Comment: @JosephK I updated my post. I do not forget to reassign my post as the best.:)

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=1; i<size; i++)
   pCurrent = pCurrent->next;

pCurrent = n;
```

This will work. But you have to keep the size variable as real size of the Linked List.

Or If you want to add element in the end always, you can follows the below steps.
Keep a extra node tail and add the element to that.

```
if(head == NULL)
{
   head = n;
   tail = n;
}
else
{
   tail->next = n;
   tail = tail->next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
node* pCurrent = ptrHead;
if( pCurrent != NULL ){
    //find tail
    while (pCurrent->next != NULL)
        pCurrent = pCurrent->next;

    // add new node at end of tail
    pCurrent->next = n;
    } else {
        pCurrent = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works.  Thank you very much, good sir.  I kept trying to assign my pCurrent node to my tail node and i was getting things all mixed up.

Comment: @JosephK This does not work because ptrHead can be equal to NULL. It is an invalid code. See my post.

Comment: This answer is wrong if the list is managed as `ptrHead == NULL` on an empty list. If the list ascribes to the head-sentinal-node philosphy (which is both confusing and imnsho putrid), it *may* work. But to dereference without checking is almost always wrong regardless.